# Where/how should I hide files so that border agents don't get to see them?

Tags: encryption, privacy

[A recent case in Canada](http://www.cbc.ca/news/canada/nova-scotia/alain-philippon-to-plead-guilty-cellphone-1.3721110) (I live in Ontario) outlined how someone who refused to disclose their encryption key at the airport got a $500 fine for interfering with border agents. This case, and many others before it (both in Canada and other countries, especially the United States) outlines a giant legal problem: when border agents are given unlimited powers to search what is essentially a person's entire history, you can end up being in a lot more trouble than you had ever expected.

Now, if I were to be traveling to other countries and back, how could I protect files that I REALLY don't want ANYONE to see--but that I have easy access to? Is the only solution really to just open a cloud storage account, and then create an encrypted file with VeraCrypt with an extremely long and complex password under AES-256 encryption, then put whatever files I want on it? That way, only if I become a suspect in a crime, will a search warrant be granted, and even then, I still have the right to refuse to disclose the key to the police.

(Note to self: it is probably a good idea to not use email clients, because they store emails on computers and phones. And oh, don't remember the usernames on banking apps for smartphones. If you don't have this data on your computer/phone, the border guards will have far less information).

Comment: TrueCrypt version 7.1a offers a way to create a hidden encrypted volume. Basically you have 2 passwords, but with one password, only the data you want them to see becomes visible, whereas with the other, everything becomes visible.

Comment: Depends on the country if they can compel a password even if it is encrypted....http://www.cbc.ca/news/canada/nova-scotia/alain-philippon-to-plead-guilty-cellphone-1.3721110

Comment: You are best to store critical data offline, some sort of cloud service to store files, access them when needed.

Comment: @Moab Are you recommending a cloud service, or offline storage? Those are mutually exclusive.

Comment: The most reliable method is to avoid illegal substances while abroad. The charge was for obstructing the officials for conducting an investigation  *after traces of cocaine had been found in the person's baggage*. His claim to privacy at that point (at least under US law, and even in intra-border circumstances) would be tenuous at best.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't mention how large the files were that you needed to conceal, but there is a technique called **steganography** that allows you to encrypt and hide one file *within* another innocent looking file, such as an MP3, photo, or video. I use it quite often to send sensitive documents to other people via regular e-mail.

Just search for "Steganography Tools" to find a large selection of software available.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this works on other Operating Systems, but I know on macOS renaming a file with a period hides it because it fools the computer into thinking it is using an operating system file. There are ways to see the file, but unless they were REALLY searching your computer, they wouldn’t find it. There is a way to show and hide hidden files, though:

*Terminal*

Show: `defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles YES`

Hide: `defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles NO`

**EDIT:**

After people not liking my first answer and my discovery of a much better solution, I would like to give a better recommendation.

Use [MacPaw Hider 2](https://macpaw.com/hider), it is only $20 for the full license, and hides and encrypts files completely. I highly recommend it. And even better is that after hiding a file, the file does not appear in the directory. The only downside (besides the price) is that it technically does not hide the files, but moves them and makes it easy to encrypt/decrypt and move them back and forth.

Comment: Yeah, that’s about as effective as turning a piece of paper face down, or closing a ledger book.  The only person you’re fooling is yourself.

Comment: @G-Man I disagree, most people don’t know about hidden files and if border security were trying to search hard drives as fast as possible, they would not check for hidden files on EVERY computer.

Comment: I doubt that border agents (anywhere other than Russia, China, North Korea and Iran, anyway) will look for *any* files on *every* computer. They will X-ray them, and maybe do a “sniff” test for drugs and explosives, and send you on your way. But anybody whose job is to search files for prohibited files will use the shell and will just get into the habit of saying ``ls -la`` instead of ``ls -l`` — how much time does it take to type the `a`? — and/or they will use `find`, which reports dot-files by default.